# Access JSON object from another file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mit-scratch

Perhaps a simple question but I am still new to JS / nodeJS.

I have a script that is doing some basic string matching (dict.js), and I am trying to access a JSON formatted object from another file (words.json) to iterate through.

The directory structure looks like:

```
scratch
- algorithms
  - dict.js
- utilities
  - words.json
```

The contents of the files are:

words.json

```
{"a": 1,"aa": 1,"aaa": 1,"aah": 1,"aahed": 1,"aahing": 1,"aahs": 1,"aal": 1}
```

dict.js

```
decode (password) {
    
    const jsonData = require('../utilities/words.json'); 
    myObj = JSON.parse(jsonData);

    for (const x in myObj) {
        console.log(x)
        // compare password against item in words.json
    }
    console.log(Object.keys(myObj).length)

    return "stub";
}
```

I am getting an error in developer tools when I create a block (this is the backend to a block in Scratch) that uses this Decode function.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Thanks

Comment: `Unexpected token o` whatever you're trying to parse is likely to be the string `[object Object]` - try `JSON.parse({})` and you'll see the same error - more than likely `jsonData` is an object, not JSON at all so `const myObj = require('../utilities/words.json');` replaces the first two lines of the function

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs environment you can directly import json file data without parsing it. For exaple:

```
const myObj = require('../utilities/words');
```

This gives you the data in your json file as a ready-to-go object.

In your case, you are trying to parse json object with `JSON.parse()` which expects stringified json. So just remove the part `JSON.parse(jsonData);`